# How to run the multiple transactions in Firestore database? I am facing issue in that

Tags: java, android, firebase, transactions, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to run the multiple transactions in firestore database in android.
but they are not working all at one time. only transaction is working right now that is of DocumentReference PostRef.

please assist in running multiple transactions.

```
db.runTransaction(new Transaction.Function<Void>() {
    @Override
    public Void apply(Transaction transaction) throws FirebaseFirestoreException {

       DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot1 = transaction.get(PostRef);
       boolean l2 = documentSnapshot1.getBoolean("l2");
        if(l2 == false) {
            transaction.update(PostRef, "l2", true);
            return null;

        }

        DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot2 = transaction.get(PostUserRef);
        long l11 = documentSnapshot2.getLong("l1");
        { transaction.update(PostRef, "l1", l11+1);

        }


        DocumentSnapshot snapshot = transaction.get(likesRef);
        boolean l1 = snapshot.getBoolean("l1");
        if (l1 == false) {

            transaction.update(likesRef, "l1", true);
            //2 transactions to update userprofile



            return null;
        } else
        {
            throw new FirebaseFirestoreException("You already liked",
                    FirebaseFirestoreException.Code.ABORTED);
        }


    }
})
```

Comment: did you try using transaction.getAll() instead of transaction.get()? here you can find [more info](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/firestore/0.13.x/Transaction?authuser=0#getAll)

Comment: i solved the issue on my own. thanks anyways

Comment: Glad to hear it. I would recommend you to post the answer here as it may prove helpful for the community.

Comment: surely, give me some time

Answer (score 2):

What I did is I Setup the multiple transactions as a function and then called those functions in the onclick event and it performed the required functions